# Changing SCNMorphers weight flattens polygons (iOS 11 beta)

Tags: ios, xcode, polygon, scenekit, flatten

I recognized in the very early beta of iOS 11 that adjusting a morphers weight (for a middle complex human model) results in a complete flattened model.

As more as I increase the weights value, the more the object is flatten.

This happens to me also in XCodes Preview-Mode (for scn files). Since the 9th beta is out now I wonder if this will be fixed. Until now I didn't find any solutions or workarounds. Does anybody has some ideas or a similar problem?

By the way: Change the morphers weight under iOS 10 and Xcode 8 works perfectly with my model.

The console prints the following error:

> [SceneKit] Error: _metalMeshForGPUComputeSkinMorph: was unable to
>   generate tangents

Comment: By ‘flatten’ do you mean it renders faceted? Sounds like normal issues with your target geometries. Did you try to remove the normal of the target geometries ? Or play with the ‘unifiesNormal’ property

Comment: Yes exactly it renders faceted. And the effect becomes stronger as more as i change the weight value towards 1.0. I also played around with the ‘unifiesNormal’ property which doesn't change anything. Same for removing the normals.

Comment: Filed a bug id:34427426

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue, any solution yet?

Comment: Very similar issue asked at Apple Dev Forum, no answered yet... :(
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9871

Comment: After they closed my last bug because of delayed replay to them i filed a new one. This time i provided an example project which renders normal on simulator and playground but shows the faceted effect on iOS devices. No matter if i change the ´unifyNormal´ or ´calculationMode´

Answer (score 2):

Actually turning ON morpher unifyNormal fix this faceted issue.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmorpher/2875540-unifiesnormals?language=objc

Should be on by default.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. No matter if change ´unifyNormal´ or ´calculationMode´ property.

Comment: That's strange, I am sure it was working for me. Try again with simple scene? When I come back to this I can make a video showing it.

Comment: Since my scene renders normal on simulator and playground (and works perfectly on iOS 10 devices) i think there is a bug related to scene kit. But indeed my model is a little bit complex (facial expressions). Could be, that it will work for less complex models.

Comment: In case anyone else is looking at this and still having a problem, unifiesNormals needs to be set to true/YES *before* SceneKit has started rendering the object (preferably before you've addNode it to the hierarchy).  It looks like it ignores any changes to this value, as well as "calculationMode", after its started rendering the SCNNode.